# How to pass parameters to a Jenkins build job over REST API using JSON

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, power-automate, jenkins-api

I am trying to trigger a Jenkins build job using Microsoft Power Automate. The build job works when I use the `buildWithParameters` endpoint, and use the following:

**Method:** POST
**URL:** `https://[Jenkins Instance URL]/[Job Path]/buildWithParameters`?

However, I need to pass in user values into the build job which requires passing in a JSON body of name:value pairs to the request.

When using curl, the following works:

```
curl -k -X POST -u "serviceuser" https://[Jenkins Instance URL]/[Job Path]/build --form json='{"parameter":[{"name":"FIELD_NAME", "value":"Value to insert"}]}
```

However, if I try the same in Power Automate using `JSON` (which looks like this using a curl to `JSON` converter):

```
{  
 "data": {
        "json": "{\"parameter\":[{\"name\":\"FIELD_NAME\", \"value\":\"Value to insert\"}]}"
         }
}
```

I get an error stating:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "source": "flow-apim-xxxx-002-xxxx-01.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "22e2f3fa-dfe6-4b27-b5f9-9f425b61250a",
    "message": "The response is not in a JSON format.",
    "innerError": "<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\"/>\n<title>Error 400 Nothing is submitted</title>\n</head>\n<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400 Nothing is submitted</h2>\n<table>\n<tr><th>URI:</th><td>[Job Path]/build</td></tr>\n<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>400</td></tr>\n<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Nothing is submitted</td></tr>\n<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>\n</table>\n<hr><a href=\"https://eclipse.org/jetty\">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.41.v20210516</a><hr/>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n"
  }
}
```

My question is how do I take the above curl command which successfully triggers the job and passes in the values in the --form parameter and convert that into a REST API call with JSON?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as by all accounts, this should be possible but I believe it's the format of the API call which is not correct. The Jenkins reference material doesn't offer much help:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/

Comment: It JSON a mandatory requirement? Jenkins accepts parameters in URL query.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe so since I need to trigger the build job and pass values from Power Automate - unless someone can provide the syntax for how to pass in parameters via REST API HTTP call?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#content-with-multipartform-data-type

Answer (score 0):

The Body of your request is indeed not valid JSON. Try sending:

```json
{
 "parameter": [
  {
    "name": "FIELD_NAME",
    "value": "Value to insert"
  }
 ]
}
```